# How to get OSM API key in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, api

I know that qustiosn was was asked before.
I have tried to find an OSM key on the web, but without success.
I know that I need to enter the API key by going in this order: web- OpenLayers Plugin-OSM/Thunderforest-Set API KEY[image]

How and where can I find the API Key that need to be paste in this window?[image]

I opened an account at [Thunderforest Console](https://manage.thunderforest.com/dashboard), paste the API key, but it did not solve the problem

Comment: edited my answer. this question has multiple answers elsewhere btw., I linked one in the answer...try searching the board in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a key for the Thunderforest maps, they provide own servers and map styles based on the OSM data (which itself is free to use without any key restriction).

You will need to [sign up an account](https://manage.thunderforest.com) (see that link in the 'enter key' window on your screenshot? there...) and [follow their instructions](https://www.thunderforest.com/docs/apikeys/) to generate your own key.

EDIT:
You will need to set the key in the OpenLayers Menu and reload the layer.
See answers [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/239773/add-an-api-key-to-qgis-for-qosm-layer).

Comment: I add the OSM  API Key, but it did not help. Is the any especially important thing that need to be done?

Comment: @NitzanMatan I can´t reproduce your problem; when I set my key and then load, say, the 'Transport' map (both via the Web -> OpenLayers -> OSM/Thunderforest menu, and in that order), it works just fine without the watermark. keep in mind, though, that, with the free plan, you will only have 150.000 tiles (!) per month.