# Using Bing Maps background for QGIS?

Tags: bing-maps, qgis-3, xyz-tiles

With the abandon of OpenLayer and the integration of the **XYZ Tiles** (in Data Browser).

Is there a way to integrate Microsoft Bing, or Here Map, as a satellite imagery layer in QGIS 3.0?

Like for Google Maps as detailed at [Will the OpenLayers Plugin be updated for QGIS3?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/272778/will-the-openlayers-plugin-be-updated-for-qgis3/)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[@MatthiasKuhn](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/9839/matthias-kuhn?tab=profile) has provided some examples in his answer to this post: [Adding Basemaps from Google or Bing in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/20191/adding-basemaps-from-google-or-bing-in-qgis/217670#217670)

For Bing, you could use:

```
http://ecn.t3.tiles.virtualearth.net/tiles/a{q}.jpeg?g=1
```

[image: Bing]

For HERE maps, you will need to [register](https://account.here.com/sign-in) in order to obtain an `APP_ID` and `APP_CODE` which can then be used for accessing [satellite map tiles](https://developer.here.com/documentation/map-tile/topics/example-satellite-map.html) via the following URL:

```
https://2.aerial.maps.cit.api.here.com/maptile/2.1/maptile/newest/satellite.day/5/15/12/256/png8?app_id={YOUR_APP_ID}&app_code={YOUR_APP_CODE}
```