# QGIS - Xyz tiles - topo servers

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, xyz-tiles

I've installed QGIS 3 today. I found the xyz tiles option and have added e.g. google, openstreet, and ESRI Topo. These all work and show the map. Now I'm looking for a topo map, so ESRI topo is a nice starting point. Unfortunately I find it a bit blurry on the font, and the lines a bit to light.

Does someone know working XYZ topo entries? I can find some XYZ tile servers for topo, but they are often not downloading tiles

Comment: related https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/272778/will-the-openlayers-plugin-be-updated-for-qgis3/272802#272802 see the update with the python script.

Comment: See comments above, they contain all the information to solve it.

Answer (score 13):

- [Open Topo Map](https://opentopomap.org/#map=5/49.000/10.000):

  ```
  https://tile.opentopomap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png
  ```

  [image: Open Topo Map]

---

- [Thunderforest (Landscape)](https://www.thunderforest.com/maps/)

  ```
  https://tile.thunderforest.com/landscape/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?apikey=YOUR_API_KEY
  ```

  [image: Thunderforest landscape]

Comment: ahh thanks, you corrected my url for it. Mine was wrong.

Comment: @Edgar - Most welcome! Hope it provides a clear-enough map :)

Comment: Yep. I also made a free thunderforest account. Trying to get that one running now too (works with an API)

Comment: @Edgar - The Thunderforest URL would be something like `https://{s}.tile.thunderforest.com/landscape/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?apikey=YOUR_API_KEY`. Just remove `{s}.`.

Comment: Yep so it is. I hadn't time to post that here back yet.

Answer (score 2):

Try also the mapy.cz XYZ tiles.

The thread is here:

https://napoveda.seznam.cz/forum/threads/68508/1

The link to the topographic "Outdoor" version is here:

[https://mapserver.mapy.cz/turist-m/{z}-{x}-{y}](https://mapserver.mapy.cz/turist-m/%7Bz%7D-%7Bx%7D-%7By%7D)

It works perfectly. Sometimes you can encounter labels in the Czech language, but it's a minor problem.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

My favorite XYZ topo server is ESRI's World Hillshade, which is not included in Klas Karlsson's [popular python script](https://nyalldawson.net/2013/03/coming-soon-in-qgis-2-0-blend-modes-for-layers/).

[http://services.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Elevation/World_Hillshade/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}](http://services.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Elevation/World_Hillshade/MapServer/tile/%7Bz%7D/%7By%7D/%7Bx%7D)

I recommend setting the blending mode to "multiply" (which effectively makes the white pixels transparent) - this looks great as an overlay ([as described here](https://nyalldawson.net/2013/03/coming-soon-in-qgis-2-0-blend-modes-for-layers/)).