# QGIS Scale Dependent Visibility not working with specific XYZ Tiles zoom level

Tags: xyz-tiles, qgis-3

How does one determine what map scale the XYZ Tiles are exporting their zoom levels at? I cannot seem to be able to configure a scale-dependent visibility to show labels and symbols on only specific XYZ Tile Zoom Levels.

For example: I am trying to configure symbols and labels to only appear in certain zoom levels for use in a leaflet map. I have been referencing the [OSM Zoom Levels](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Zoom_levels).

I have been testing with zoom level 11, which *should* correspond to 1:250000 map scale. I have configured my labels and symbols to have a scale dependent visibility from 1:249999 to 1:250001, which should **only** show such labels on zoom 11 on an XYZ Tiles export. QGIS properly shows these layers only on the 1:250000 map scale. However upon export the layers are not visible on zoom 11, which leads me to believe my zoom 11 is not exactly exporting at 1:250000.

I have also checked out this [MapTiler website](https://www.maptiler.com/google-maps-coordinates-tile-bounds-projection/) and confirmed that my XYZ Tiles export matches Google's tile names and bounds, which supports that the tiles exporting at 1:250000.

I have referenced some [other questions](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/276323/qgis-3-0-xyz-tile-openstreetmap-text-is-too-small-to-see) which led me to play with the DPI on export, but this does not fix the issue either.

Any ideas? Am I missing something on how the map scale, DPI, CRS etc. and XYZ Tiles interact? How can I confirm that my XYZ Tiles are exporting as per the [OSM Zoom Levels](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Zoom_levels)?

Edit: After much trial and error I have found for my layer to print only at XYZ Tile Zoom 11 (1:250000) at 96dpi (default), I need to have the layer visible to a Scale Dependent Visibility of **1:288895**. I am not sure why there is a 15% difference between the intended and actual XYZ Tile Zoom Scale. Can anyone shed any light on this.

Comment: I'm not sure if I follow. I am not importing tiles but exporting/creating custom tiles from a very large map. The Map Scale shown in QGIS doesn't seem to correspond to the Map Scale used by the XYZ Tile feature, since it takes a layer visibility of 1:288895 scale to display on the 1:250000 XYZ Tile Zoom Level 11.

This is only necessary since an XYZ Tile export from zoom 5 to zoom 17 creates very wacky symbol and label interactions (they become absurdly huge above zoom 10), so I intended on duplicating each layer and manually adjusting each symbol and label to look nicely at each zoom level.

Comment: Nevermind. I misunderstood your question. (I thought you were importing an existing XYZ tile, not creating your own.)

Comment: Ran into the same kind of issue on previous qgis version. Could you precise which kind of export you are using ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

QGIS does not use the OSM Zoom Levels Scales but instead uses **Spherical Mercator Zoom Level Scales** as shown on [this page](https://www.maptiler.com/google-maps-coordinates-tile-bounds-projection/).

From this page you will see that Zoom Level 11 corresponds to a Map Scale (at 96 dpi) of **1:288895.85**. Upon setting the scale-dependent visibility, the XYZ Tile label will now behave as expected.