Text size on XYZ tile maps unreadable
When I load an XYZ tile like OpenStreetMap into a QGIS 3 project, the text on the features is microscopically small and unreadable unless you zoom way in.  How do I make the text readable at lower zoom levels?

Looks fine to me. What OS, display settings and monitor resolution do you have?

High DPI/Retina display? https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/276440/2856

Turns out there is a simple fix for my problem.  When adding an xyz tile, go to Edit Connection > Tile Resolution > High.
