# QGIS 3.0 Hybrid Tile Server URLs

Tags: qgis, tiles, tile-server

I've recently come into a new position where I'm using QGIS instead of ESRI and am learning the ropes on handling all the things ESRI comes out of the box with that QGIS doesn't.

I've found tile server URLs for OpenStreetMap and Bing Aerial, but nothing of the hybrid variation. Does anyone have information on anything like Bing or Google Hybrid tiles with worldwide/US coverage?

Comment: https://qms.nextgis.com/ https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/20191/adding-basemaps-from-google-or-bing-in-qgis https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/20191/adding-basemaps-from-google-or-bing-in-qgis

Comment: I saw that thread and it doesn't really cover QGIS 3. The OpenLayers plugin hasn't been ported to the new version yet.

Comment: Scroll down, one of the answers lower on the page has URLs.

Comment: Here's script by Klas Karlsson you can paste into the python console, or you can just copy the 
urls and add xyz tile layers manually: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/klakar/QGIS_resources/master/collections/Geosupportsystem/python/qgis_basemaps.py

Comment: Also, if you install QGIS 2.18, you add layers using the quickmapservices plugin, and then harvest the links from the layer properties. It's usually a good idea to have the latest long term release of QGIS installed even if you're using the newest version. The new versions are usually somewhat buggy.

Comment: quickmapservices has been ported to 3.0, as of a couple of days ago, so can use that as well as XYZ provider

Answer (score 1):

### The plugin QuickMapServices gives you access to many worldwide base layers, which can be easily added to your map from a menu.

Install from the Plugins menu > Manage and install plugins > search for quickmapservices > install plugin > activate by checking the box next the plugin name.
[image]

Access the plugin through the Web menu. By default, you have access to a few reliable base layers.

[image]

At your own risk, you can also access a wide variety of "contributed" base layers, of varying reliability and accuracy. Go to Settings > More Services > Get contributed pack. In my experience, the contributed layers are accurate, but they don't all work. Some are missing tiles, while others only work at certain zoom levels.

[image]

### You can also manually add any layer for which you have a URL.

See the answer provided by Matthias Kuhn to this question (scroll down, it's near the bottom of the page) for help [adding an XYZ tiles layer, and some URLs.](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/20191/adding-basemaps-from-google-or-bing-in-qgis)

And see the answer to this question for help [adding WMS layers.](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/276815/obtaining-base-maps-base-layers-in-qgis-3-0)