# Google maps error in OpenLayers plugin in QGIS

Tags: qgis, openlayers-2, google-maps

I was using the Google maps on `OpenLayers` plugin in QGIS 2.16.3 successfully before but today when I tried it the page appears as shown in the figure;

[image]

I tried re-installing the plugin but this keeps on coming.

Have there been any changes to the plugin?

Comment: Google Maps changed their terms of use - this openlayers plugin uses an api key and it is limited after 2,500 uses a day.

Comment: Note: QuickMapServices works still (Tested in QGIS 2.16.3)

Comment: @Mapperz Thanks for your reply. The google maps didn't work from the first time i tried today. Did you mean 2,500 per day for all the users?
QuickMapServices does not give the google maps option. I get only, eatlas, landsat, mapsurfer, nasa and OSM.

Answer (score 5):

QuickMapServices (**version 0.19.9)** has the Google Maps Option

This must be a change to the github version

[image]

Or upgrade to QGIS 3.2 and use the XYZ tiles 
[Will the OpenLayers Plugin be updated for QGIS3?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/272778/will-the-openlayers-plugin-be-updated-for-qgis3)

Comment: Thanks @Mapperz. The latest version I installed for QuickMapServices is 0.19.10.1. Looks like unfortunately the Google maps option is dropped.

Comment: Google maps does not come preloaded in QMS. Did you install the contributed pack under: Quickmap services settings > more services > get contributed pack?

Comment: Installed 'as is' in 2016.

Comment: Accept the answer then. The whole click on the green button really isn't rocket science, though you seem to be particularly allergic to thanking people for helpling you.