# Download opentopo maps layer in QGIS 3.2.2 and adding GPS coordinates

Tags: qgis, download

I would like to create a topographic map around Kinanira (Uganda) with QGIS, in which I can load my GPS coordinates from my soil samples.

In order to get a better overview, it would be useful to color the reports according to different pH values.

Comment: There are some really good guides to QGIS on the web and as books. Follow the tutorials and guides here: https://qgis.org/en/docs/index.html for a start. This site is best for when you get stuck and have a more specific question.

Comment: Related https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/272778/will-the-openlayers-plugin-be-updated-for-qgis3

Comment: Regarding this part of your question, "color the reports according to different pH values," I assume the pH values are attributes of the soil sample points. Use [categorized symbology](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/vector_properties.html#categorized-renderer) or graduated symbology.

Comment: Not OpenTopo, but you might also be interested... You can download SRTM 90m Digital Elevation Data (3 arc second) resolution for Uganda from http://www.diva-gis.org/gdata in RRaster format with a VRT and view directly in QGIS.

Answer (score 2):

You dont really download the open topo base layer but just display it as a base map (meaning you just download tile in image format from the web).

One easy way to do it is by using the QuickMapServices plugin (go to Pluging>Manage and Install Plugings... to instal it if you need, then in the plugins setting go to More service>Get contributed pack to access lot of base maps including the OpenTopoMap).

Keep in mind that all (?) of these base maps are created for screen display (at low resolution to have faster loading time) so getting a printed document from one of them could be disappointing (low resolution and/or very small label and feature...).

As said in comment your question is a bit to general to get an complete answer but adding point from GPS, adding attribute, and setting symbology, are really basic GIS task and you will easily find tutorials. If you get stuck feel free to ask specific question....