# OpenLayers plugin in QGIS 3.6

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-3, google-maps, basemap

I can't find OpenLayers Plugin to install in QGIS 3.6.

I want to open Google Earth in order to add coordinates and open satellite image to start mapping.

Comment: OpenLayers is listed as an _Experimental Plugin_ which you would need to enable via the `Settings`. However, it is highly recommended to instead use the **QuickMapServices** plugin as this contains many more maps and is frequently updated.

Comment: Possible duplicated https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/272778/will-the-openlayers-plugin-be-updated-for-qgis3

Comment: Which under QuickMapservcices would give same satellite view like google earth? Would you please let me know the steps to enable OpenLayers plugin from settings?

Answer (score 8):

Instead of using OpenLayersPlugin (which, as already mentioned, causes trouble sometimes and is experimental) I recommend to directly add XYZ Tiles of Google to QGIS:

1. Create a new connection for XYZ Tiles in your QGIS Browser:

[image]

2. Add a new Connection with the URL and give it a name:

[image]

3. You can now add this service to your canvas:

[image]

The connection is saved. So once you created it, it will be available on your PC, no need to reconnect every time.

Here is a list of possible Google URLs:

- Google Maps: https://mt1.google.com/vt/lyrs=r&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}
- Google Satellite: http://www.google.cn/maps/vt?lyrs=s@189&gl=cn&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}
- Google Satellite Hybrid: https://mt1.google.com/vt/lyrs=y&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}
- Google Terrain: https://mt1.google.com/vt/lyrs=t&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}
- Google Roads: https://mt1.google.com/vt/lyrs=h&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}

---

Reference and Source: https://geogeek.xyz/how-to-add-google-maps-layers-in-qgis-3.html

Comment: Can't thank you enough for your support, appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

if you want to use OpenLayersPlugin check experimental flag under settings (like @Joseph pointed out):

[image]

If you want to use QuickMapServices then load the plugin and go to settings and then to the More services Tab and Click the "Get contributed pack"

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can also use XYZ tiles. In this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M-WfXHbGOlw&t=1s Klas Karlson explains how to load them. In the description of the video you have a a link for the python script, and you will have a lot of base maps that you can use.  XYZ tiles are available in the browser pannel. If you do not see the browser pannel, go to view/pannels and activate browser. Check the video and give it a try