# Add an API key to QGIS

Tags: qgis, api

I can't seem to get this ([Add an API key to QGIS for QOSM layer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/239773/add-an-api-key-to-qgis-for-qosm-layer/295182?noredirect=1#comment473954_295182)) to work.

I need to add an API key to QGIS for OpenCycleMap. I'm trying to follow the path `Web > OpenLayer plugin > OSM/Thunderforest > Set API Key` as described in the linked question, but my menu does not have the "OSM/Thunderforest" option.

How do I update the OpenLayers Plugin?

Comment: Did you sign up for a Thunderforest account?

Comment: Yes I did sign up for an account.

Comment: I am facing the same problem. Does someone have the answer?